# Logging Out AspNet Client From IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, identityserver4

How to log out AspNet MVC client from IdentityServer4?

If I trigger

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
```

from Aspnet MVC Client then all clients including AspNetCore MVC Client logged out correctly. But if I click logout from IdentityServer 4, only AspNetCore MVC client logged out but Aspnet MVC Client stays logged in. Any help highly appreciate

Comment: Did you set `BackChannelLogoutUri` for _Aspnet MVC Client_? You'll have to create the endpoint and make sure IdentityServer can access it.

Comment: I add BackChannelLogoutUri from IdentityServer4 point to /Home/Logout contain Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(); but my AspNet still logging in